# Whats the difference between subClass sc = new subClass() and superClass sc = new subClass?

Tags: java, object, initialization

```
class superClass {}

class subClass extends superClass{}

public class test
{

    public static void main()

{

    superClass sc1 = new subClass();
    subClass sc2 = new subClass();
    //whats the difference between the two objects created using the above code?

}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple explanation :
When you use

```
SuperClass obj = new SubClass();
```

Only public methods that are defined in `SuperClass` are accessible. Methods defined in `SubClass` are not.

When you use

```
SubClass obj = new SubClass();
```

public methods defined in `SubClass` are also accessible along with the `SuperClass` public methods.

Object created in both cases is the same.

Ex:

```
public class SuperClass {

  public void method1(){

  }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  public void method2()
  {
 
  }
}

SubClass sub = new SubClass();
sub.method1();  //Valid through inheritance from SuperClass
sub.method2();  // Valid

SuperClass superClass = new SubClass();
superClass.method1();
superClass.method2(); // Compilation Error since Reference is of SuperClass so only SuperClass methods are accessible.
```

Answer (score 2):

> whats the difference between the two objects created using the above code?

The two objects are exactly the same. What's different is the type of the variable where the object reference is stored. In practice, this means that if there are any methods specific to `subClass`, you'll be able to access them through `sc2` but not through `sc1` (the latter would require a cast).

Answer (score 2):

In both the cases, objects of `subClass` will be created, but the references will be different.

With the reference of `superClass` i.e `sc1` , you won't be able to invoke the methods present in the `subClass` but not in the `superClass`. You will require casting to invoke the `subClass` methods.

Like :

```
class superClass {
   public void superClassMethod(){
   }
}

class subClass extends superClass{
   public void subClassMethod(){
   }
}
```

Now :

```
public class test
{
  public static void main(){

    superClass sc1 = new subClass();
    subClass sc2 = new subClass();
    //whats the difference between the two objects created using the above code?


    sc2.subClassMethod(); //this is valid

    sc1.subClassMethod(); // this is a compiler error, 
                          // as no method named subClassMethod
                          // is present in the superClass as the
                          // reference is of superClass type

   // for this you require a type cast

   (subClass)sc1.subClassMethod(); // Now this is valid

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The objects are the same.  However, because `sc1` is declared as type `superClass` you cannot use `subClass` methods on it without casting.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers, because the constructed object is really an object of type  `SubClass` you can cast it to `SubClass` and call the methods:

```
SuperClass superClass = new SubClass();
superClass.method1();
((SubClass)superClass).method2();
```

Answer (score 0):

just think like this.
when you using the parent (super class) reference you will get access to only the things(variable , methods) that parent has. but if you use the reference of child you will get everything that the parent and child have (child inherit properties from parent).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SuperClass {
    
      public void method1(){
    
      }

 public void method3(){
    
      }


    }
    
    public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
      public void method2()
      {
    
      }
@override
 public void method3(){
    
      }
    }
    
    SubClass sub = new SubClass();
    sub.method1();  //Valid through inheritance from SuperClass
    sub.method2();  // Valid 
    sub.method3();//valid 


   superClass sc1 = new subClass();
    superClass.method1();
superClass.method2();////compilation error: cannot find symbol method
superClass.method3();//run over ridden version

superClass sc1 = new subClass();
```

You can invoke all the methods defined in theSuperClass  for the reference sc1, (which is actually holding a Subclass object),
This is because a subclass instance possesses all the properties of its superclass.

However, you CANNOT invoke methods defined in the  subclass for the reference sc1, .

// CANNOT invoke methods in Subclass as sc1 is a superclass reference

This is because sc1 is a reference to the Superclass, which does not know about methods defined in the subclass .

sc1 is a reference to the Superclass, but holds an object of its subclass . The reference sc1, however, retains its internal identity. In our example, the subclass  overrides methods Method3 . sc1.Method3  invokes the overridden version defined in the subclass , instead of the version defined in superclass. This is because sc1 is in fact holding a subclass object internally.