# What is the difference between "ParentClass objectName1= new SubClass() " and "SubClass objectName2 = new SubClass()"?

Tags: java, inheritance

I was wondering if there is any functional difference between those two ways of creating an object in a class that extends from another.

I'm just working with basic Inheritance, nothing complex beyond Cat extends Mammal and that kind of things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the difference between subClass sc = new subClass() and superClass sc = new subClass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596193/whats-the-difference-between-subclass-sc-new-subclass-and-superclass-sc-ne)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ParentClass objectName = new SubClass()` - parent class reference is holding child class object

```
class ParentClass{
 void m1(){
   System.out.println("parent m1");
  }
 void m2(){
   System.out.println("parent m2");
  }
}

class SubClass extends ParentClass{
//subclass overriding parent class m1 method
 @Override
 void m1(){
   System.out.println("child m1");
  }
 void m3(){
   System.out.println("child m3");
  }
}

class Test{
public static void main(String[] args){
  ParentClass p = new SubClass();
  p.m1();// out puts child m1 as child class is overriding m1 method
  p.m2();//out puts parent m2 as child class is not overriding m2 method
  p.m3();//gives compile time error as parent class reference doesn't know about m3 method

}
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, that was really clear, i think i do get it now.

Comment: key difference: if we use like this, the object can have only methods from parent class (if the methods is overridden by child class then that is effective, but methods child class have alone can't be accessed)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do:

- `ParentClass objectName = new SubClass()` is typically used when you only need the features of `ParentClass` and don't care about the actual implementation `SubClass`. A prominent example of this is containers such as `List` where one often does e.g.  `List<String> objectName = new ArrayList<String>()`. What one needs is a list and in the remainder of the code does typically not care about how the list is implemented. In your case, if all you need is the features of the `Mammal` you can use this and your code will also work the day you want to use it with `Dog` instead of `Cat`. In the spirit of generalization, you could always try to use the most generic type (oldest ancestor so to say) possible. Some integrated development environments actually have a function to try to replace the types of variables by the most generic type which does not break the code.
- `SubClass objectName = new SubClass()` on the other hand lets you use all the details of `SubClass` in the rest of the code without having to do any type cast (which may in principle fail for the previous case if some part of the code assigns a different object which is not `SubClass` or a descendant thereof).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it helped me understand the differences between them.

Answer (score 2):

The instance returned by`new SubClass()` is not effected by the type of reference you assign it to - the same constructor is run, and you get back an object with the same functionality.

Assigning this newly created object to a reference higher-up in the hierarchy is usually used to signify that you won't use any `SubClass` specific methods, and your code is not tied down to assuming what subclass you're using.

Answer (score 1):

## case1:

```
   ParentClass objectName = new SubClass() //  use only when you need some features of parent class.
```

1). objectName (refrence of your parent class) is having the object of Subclass.

2). in this case you can access the public methods of your parent class,but cannot access the methods of subclass.

## case2:

```
SubClass objectName = new SubClass() // use only when you need features of subclass.
```

1). object created in both  cases are same.

2). you can access  both (methods of superclass and subclass).

Answer (score 0):

First statement reference ObjectName1 is referring to child class, where as in the second  ObjectName2 is referring to its own object, if you call the methods of parent object it will call the methods of child class object if its present